# How to display colored XML code inside HTML textarea

Tags: html, xml, colors, textbox

I'm building a web application with Symfony , and I want to allow users to post an XML request to remote servers.

I've designed the page with a textarea where they should put the XML code and I was wondering if I can make it colored so they can edit their codes easily .

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea rows="20" cols="70" name="request" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Put Your SOAP Request here"></textarea>
</div>
```

Any Idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you try something? You will increase the chance of getting an answer if you provide some code.

Comment: My code is a basic HTML textarea , I did not try anything as I don't know the tools I should use

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CodeMirror:
http://codemirror.net/

You'll probably have to add some custom Javascript to your textarea field to make it work.

There seems to be a bundle for this, but I'm not sure how reliable it is:
https://packagist.org/packages/nitrado/code-mirror-bundle